# Return custom JOOQ record when using a common table expression or subquery

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am working on a complex query that contains a common table expression and multiple subqueries. I am trying to keep the code readable by splitting it into methods but I am struggling a bit.

Is there a way to return a custom JOOQ record when building a common table expression or subquery instead of the standard JOOQ Records?

An example of a common table expression:

```
public static final String COLUMN1 = "column_1";
public static final String COLUMN2 = "column_2";
public static final String COLUMN3 = "column_3";
public static final String COLUMN4 = "column_4";
public static final String COLUMN5 = "column_5";
public static final String COLUMN6 = "column_6";

public CommonTableExpression<Record6<Long, String, String, LocalDate, LocalDate, Boolean>> getMyFirstCTE() {
    var t = MY_TABLE.as("t");

    return name("t")
            .fields(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5, COLUMN6)
            .as(
                    select(
                            t.COLUMN1,
                            t.COLUMN2,
                            t.COLUMN3,
                            t.COLUMN4,
                            t.COLUMN5,
                            t.COLUMN6)
                    .from(t)
                    .where(t.COLUMN6.isFalse()));
}
```

and an example of a subquery:

```
public Table<Record6<Long, String, String, LocalDate, LocalDate, Boolean>> getMyFirstTable() {
    var t = MY_TABLE.as("t");

    return select(
                    t.COLUMN1,
                    t.COLUMN2,
                    t.COLUMN3,
                    t.COLUMN4,
                    t.COLUMN5,
                    t.COLUMN6)
            .from(t)
            .where(t.COLUMN6.isFalse()).asTable("t");
}
```

If the caller wants to use the fields from the common table expression it's expressed as shown below (same holds for the subquery):

```
    var cte = getMyFirstCTE();
var column1 = cte.field(COLUMN1, Long.class);
var column2 = cte.field(COLUMN2, String.class);
var column3 = cte.field(COLUMN3, String.class);
var column4 = cte.field(COLUMN4, LocalDate.class);
var column5 = cte.field(COLUMN5, LocalDate.class);
var column6 = cte.field(COLUMN6, Boolean.class);
```

It would be nice to have these signatures instead:

```
public static CommonTableExpression<MyFirstRecord> getMyFirstCTE() {}

public static Table<MyFirstRecord> getMyFirstTable() {}
```

Not only for readability but also to (hopefully) not having to explicitly add the class type and be able to do something like `MyFirstRecord.COLUMN1`.

Is there a way to do this?